Calculating the least-squares fit of two Sentinel 2 rasters in python
I'm trying to replicate the Single-band–multi-pass method of methane column retrieval from Sentinel 2 data as outlined here.
https://amt.copernicus.org/articles/14/2771/2021/
They give the formula of:
ΔRSBMP = (cR12 - R'12) / R'12

Where c is the least-squares fitting of all values of R12 in the scene against all values of R′12. R12 is the scene with the methane emission and R'12 is the scene without the methane emission.
Which is simple enough, but I'm unsure of how to calculate the value of c.
The paper says "We calculate c by least-squares fitting of all values of R12 in the scene against all values of R'12, using a first-order linear regression with an intercept of zero."
I've found this tool but I'm unsure how to use it with my rasters. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html
As it stands my code for the formula looks like this
# Load the GeoTIFF files
with rasterio.open(r"C:\GIS_Course\Sentinel-2_active_emission.GTiff") as active_emission_file:
    active_emission_data = active_emission_file.read(1)  # the only band (band 1) is B12 from the data

with rasterio.open(r"C:\GIS_Course\Sentinel-2_no_emission.GTiff") as no_emission_file:
    no_emission_data = no_emission_file.read(1)   # the only band (band 1) is B12 from the data

# Calculate methane column
methane_column = (active_emission_data - no_emission_data) / no_emission_data

Can anyone tell me how to calculate 'c'?
------ update 1 -----
Here is how I am calculating C:
# Open raster files
with rasterio.open(r"C:\GIS_Course\EGM722\Project\Sentinel-2_active_emission.GTiff") as active_emission_file:
    active_emission_data = active_emission_file.read(1)

with rasterio.open(r"C:\GIS_Course\EGM722\Project\Sentinel-2_no_emission.GTiff") as no_emission_file:
    no_emission_data = no_emission_file.read(1)

# converting rasters to arrays
active_emission_flat = active_emission_data.flatten()
no_emission_flat = no_emission_data.flatten()

# Prepare the data for linear regression
X = active_emission_flat.reshape(-1, 1)  # Feature matrix (active emission)
y = no_emission_flat  # Target vector (no emission)

# Fit linear regression model with fit_intercept=False
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
model.fit(X, y)

# Coefficients
c = model.coef_

# Calculate methane column
methane_column = (c * active_emission_data - no_emission_data) / no_emission_data

When I run this I get a map but it's showing terrain features, which indicates that the correction hasn't worked as those things should be cancelled out.


With intercept =0, it is total of cells of one raster (function) divided by cells total of second (argument). You can use ratio of means as well

Since you're working with arrays you can use scikit linear model. This has a fit_intercept method that you will set to False. Scroll down on that page for some examples.

@LisanAlGIS
I think I've implemented it correctly but I still only see terrain features and no methane column. The terrain features should be cancelled out by this process so I'm missing something from the data processing obviously.

Then please add your implementation to the questions so others have a chance to help you.

@LisanAlGIS I've updated the original post with that information now. Thanks for taking a look.

@FelixIP I also tried your method and got a similar number to the method I've added above, but the resultant map was similar anyway

You could increase your chances further by adding the datasets for download. You might also want to remove the filepaths to something relative, as they can sometimes reveal unnecessary personal information (I went to the same university). Last but not least, you might find some useful information here, which is the same workflow. Please remember to update if you find a solution so future users can make sense of it too.

Okay @LisanAlGIS . I've made those changes to the file paths and added the GeoTIFF files as a google drive download.
I'll take a look a the link you said. Hopefully I'll have some luck in solving this. Thanks for your suggestions in how to better format the question.

@Zelcon01 I mixed up the filepaths by accident and ran your script with the datasets reversed...and that looks more promising since I get some methane response at the biodigestion plant? Could it be that simple of an error?

I just flipped them to see if I could detect anything on the map and nothing.
Also, I updated the files on the google drive about an hour ago to be completely sure there were no clouds affecting the scenes chosen. If you have the old one for the non emission scene, it could be that?

What an odd coincidence then, after redownloading it disappeared yes. Looks like your code is doing what it is supposed to do - maybe the scene selection or preprocessing just does not offer a better result? I would maybe try one of the other approaches mentioned in the paper. If you look at Figure 2d you see a lot of noise/artefacts/terrain. Sorry, I'm out of ideas :)
PS: On the gdrive I can now see your name+mail.

@LisanAlGIS I think I've done it.
You shared this earlier
https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-geospatial/methane-emission-monitoring/monitor_methane_ch4_emission_point_sources.ipynb
and I managed to adapt the code to work in mine by playing with it.
I'll write up a full answer here tomorrow as it's very late and I'm knackered.
Thanks so much for your help.

So based on this github jupyter notebook I found an answer.
#https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-geospatial/methane-emission-monitoring/monitor_methane_ch4_emission_point_sources.ipynb
I ran the following code and it worked great. Thanks again to @LisanAIGIS for the help.
def compute_correction_factor(active_emission_data, no_emission_data):
    """
    Compute a correction factor c via linear regression
    with the following equation: active_emission_data = c*no_emission_data
    """
    # get flattened arrays for regression
    y = active_emission_data.flatten()
    x = no_emission_data.flatten()

    # replace NaN values with 0
    y = np.nan_to_num(y)
    x = np.nan_to_num(x)

    assert y.shape == x.shape, "Shapes of two provided arrays are incompatible!"

    # fit linear model using least squares regression
    x = x[:, np.newaxis]
    c, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(x, y, rcond=None)

    return c[0]

def compute_corrected_fractional_reflectance_change(active_emission_data, no_emission_data):
    """
    Compute corrected fractional reflectance change between base and monitoring scene
    """
    # get correction factor
    c = compute_correction_factor(active_emission_data, no_emission_data)

    # get corrected fractional reflectance change
    frac_change = ((c * no_emission_data - active_emission_data) / active_emission_data)

    return frac_change

# Open raster files
with rasterio.open(r"C:\GIS_Course\EGM722\Project\Sentinel-2_active_emission.GTiff") as active_emission_file:
    active_emission_data = active_emission_file.read(1)

with rasterio.open(r"C:\GIS_Course\EGM722\Project\Sentinel-2_no_emission.GTiff") as no_emission_file:
    no_emission_data = no_emission_file.read(1)

# Compute corrected fractional reflectance change
frac_change = compute_corrected_fractional_reflectance_change(active_emission_data, no_emission_data)


Glad to see you got it working. It does look like the issue was indeed calculating the fractional change the other way around, subtracting/dividing by the active_emission_data instead of no_emission_data?

@LisanAlGIS Although the code I posted does that, I don't think that was the issue.
In this paper https://amt.copernicus.org/articles/14/2771/2021/ it states it the way round I had it originally. I'm going to play with it some more and see if it makes a difference or not. Will report back as soon as I can.
The way that the AWS script calculated fractional reflectance change and computed the correction factor seems to be what did it. Thank you again for linking that to me; I don't think I would have found it on my own.
